# Найти максимум одномерного массива c помощью рекурсии

Tags: c#, массивы, рекурсия

На курсах получил задание: реализовать метод поиска максимума в массиве **рекурсивно**. Изначально попытался рекурсивно "повторить" итеративный вариант, т.е. передавать в метод индекс и обновленный максимум. Задание проверяется юнит тестами (написанные авторами курса). Описанный мною подход работал на всех тестах, кроме одного: перфоманс тест, который проверяет реализацию на время (`[Timeout(5_000)]`) на довольно большом массиве (длинной 10_000_000). Переписал метод и теперь код выглядит так:

```
public static int FindMaximum(int[] array)
{
    if (array is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException($"source cannot be null.");
    }

    if (array.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"source cannot be empty.");
    }

    return FindMax(array, 0, array.Length);
}

private static int FindMax(int[] array, int start, int length)
{
    if (start == length - 1)
    {
        return array[start];
    }

    int mid = (start + length) / 2;
    int left = FindMax(array, start, mid);
    int right = FindMax(array, mid, length);

    return (left > right) ? left : right;
}
```

Этот вариант проходит все тесты (в том числе и последний "злополучный"). Видимо этот тест как раз и преследовал цель указать обучающемуся (т.е. мне) на проблемы оптимизации и быстродействия. Впереди ряд задач на рекурсию. Может есть какой-нибудь гайдолайн по оптимизации рекурсивного подхода, в какую сторону смотреть? Заранее спасибо.
P.S. Это мой первый вопрос и изначально я его сформулировал не верно. Спасибо сообществу, что указали мне на это и прошу прощения.

Comment: Мне интересно мнение других людей -- для чего в этой задаче фигурирует слово "рекурсия"?

Comment: Максимум в одномерном массиве прекрасно ищется за O(N) и без рекурсии, к чему усложнять себе жизнь?

Comment: А вот вопрос ваш непонятен. "Почему" что? Почему проходит? Или почему быстрее? Если быстрее - то с чем сравниваем? Если вопрос про объснять, как работает computational complexity - книг в сети море, что читали? Что именно непонятно? А ещё нужно рассказать про CLR (что именно?), про JIT (что именно?)... не надо задавать более одного вопроса в теме - такие вопросы быстро закрываются.

Comment: *Этот вариант проходит все тесты (гораздо быстрее чем другие), но мне, как новичку, хотелось бы знать - почему?* Перечислите, какие методы поиска максимума используют те самые "другие".

Comment: А не проще было бы реализовать код в виде `switch() case`?

Comment: @Andrew для того, чтобы научить оценивать глубину рекурсии при разных подходах и объяснить tail call оптимизацию.

Comment: @AK а по моему - отличный вопрос, отличный тестовый пример, с подвохом, и в теле вопроса есть все, чтобы дать хороший ответ :)

Comment: @PashaPash или её еще называют "хвостовая рекурсия".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Оригинальный вариант у вас падал не по таймауту, а по переполнению стека с StackOverflowException.

И тест проверяет не производительность, а ваше понимание потенициальных проблем при использовании рекурсии.

Каждый рекурсивный вызов занимает место в стеке под локальные переменные и под переданные ему параметры. Так что каждый вызов стоит примерно 12 байт в стеке. При линейном рекурсивном вызове на массиве стек выглядит примерно так

```
FindMax(array, 10000000, ..)
FindMax(array, 9999999, ..)
.....
FindMax(array, 1, ..)
FindMax(array, 0, ..)
FindMaximum(array)
```

Размер стека фиксированный, порядка мегабайт, и на 10000000 вызовах он просто переполняется.

Разделение массива на резко уменьшило глубину рекурсии, с 10M до примерно 24.

Вместо разделения массива можно использовать оптимизацию [Tail Call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). Если ваш рекурсивный  возвращает в качестве результата или значение, или результат вызова себя, и не делает кроме этого вызова в return других рекурсивных вызовов, то при рекурсивном вызове компилятор может выбросить стек текущего вызова.

Например:

```
private static int FindMax(int[] array, int index, int currentMax = 0)
{
    if (index == 0)
    {
        currentMax = array[0];
    }
    
    if (index == array.Length)
    {
        return currentMax;
    }
    else
    {
        currentMax = Math.Max(currentMax, array[index]);
        return FindMax(array, index + 1, currentMax);
    }
}
```

Вызов в стеке

```
FindMax(array, 0, ..)
FindMaximum(array)
```

заменится на вызов

```
FindMax(array, 1, ..)
FindMaximum(array)
```

и дальше, вплоть до

```
FindMax(array, 10000000, ..)
FindMaximum(array)
```

и результат вернется прямо в FindMaximum.

Отрабатывает за 28ms на 10000000 на моей машине :)

Проблема только в том, что компилятор C# не умеет явно требовать этой оптимизации от JIT (компилятор F#, например, умеет). И она срабатывает только в Release, и только в 64 bit (т.е. нужно или собирать или с явным указанием x64, или в AnyCPU со снятой Prefer 32 bit в свойствах проекта).

Если ваше тестовое окружение запускается под x86 (32 bit) - то оптимизация работать не будет, и тест будет падать. Тогда оставляйте вариант с разделением массива.

Полный код, для простоты проверки:

```
private static int FindMax(int[] array, int index, int currentMax = 0)
{
    if (index == 0)
    {
        currentMax = array[0];
    }
        
    if (index == array.Length)
    {
        return currentMax;
    }
    else
    {
        currentMax = Math.Max(currentMax, array[index]);
        return FindMax(array, index + 1, currentMax);
    }
}

public static int FindMaximum(int[] array)
{
    if (array is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException($"source cannot be null.");
    }

    if (array.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"source cannot be empty.");
    }

    return FindMax(array, 0);
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] array = new int[10000000];
    array[array.Length - 50] = 42;

    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Console.WriteLine(FindMaximum(array));
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Comment: `порядка мегабайт` - пропущено число.

Comment: @aepot не пропущено, я просто не помню сколько именно там мб стек по умолчанию :)

Comment: [1 мегабайт](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28658130/12888024) для x86 (32 бит)

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, как у автора получилось так, что версия с рекурсией выполняется быстрее, чем классическая версия нахождения максимума. Я решил проверить, насколько быстро выполняются методы:

1. классический линейный поиск максимума (`FindMaxClassic`)
2. рекурсивный метод, предложенный автором (`FindMaximumAuthor`)
3. рекурсивный метод, предлагаемый мной (`FindMaxRecursive`)

Итак, я написал три метода и поместил их в один класс `IntArrayHelper`:

```
public static class IntArrayHelper
{
    public static int FindMaxClassic(int[] array)
    {
        if (array == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
        }

        if (!array.Any())
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Array is empty");
        }

        var max = array[0];
        for (var i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] > max)
            {
                max = array[i];
            }
        }

        return max;
    }

    public static int FindMaxRecursive(int[] array)
    {
        if (array == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
        }

        if (!array.Any())
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Array is empty");
        }

        var max = FindMaxRec(array, 0);
        return max;
    }

    private static int FindMaxRec(int[] array, int from)
    {
        // Дошли до крайнего правого элемента массива? заканчиваем рекурсию
        if (from == array.Length - 1)
        {
            return array[from];
        }

        var current = array[from];
        var max = FindMaxRec(array, from + 1);
        return max > current ? max : current;
    }

    public static int FindMaximumAuthor(int[] array)
    {
        if (array is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"source cannot be null.");
        }

        if (array.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"source cannot be empty.");
        }

        return FindMax(array, 0, array.Length);
    }

    private static int FindMax(int[] array, int start, int length)
    {
        if (start == length - 1)
        {
            return array[start];
        }

        int mid = (start + length) / 2;
        int left = FindMax(array, start, mid);
        int right = FindMax(array, mid, length);

        return (left > right) ? left : right;
    }
}
```

И сделал тест на 10000 запусков каждого метода на одинаковом наборе случайно сгенерированного списка массивов. Тестирующий код:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WarmUp();

    var random = new Random();
    var testSrc = new List<int[]>();
    const int n = 10000;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var arrayLength = random.Next(1, n);
        var array = new int[arrayLength];
        for (var j = 0; j < arrayLength; j++)
        {
            array[j] = random.Next(-n, n);
        }

        testSrc.Add(array);
    }

    var timeClassic = TestTimeExecution(IntArrayHelper.FindMaxClassic, testSrc);
    var timeRecursive = TestTimeExecution(IntArrayHelper.FindMaxRecursive, testSrc);
    var timeAuthor = TestTimeExecution(IntArrayHelper.FindMaximumAuthor, testSrc);

    Console.WriteLine($"Classic         : {timeClassic.TotalMilliseconds}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Recursive       : {timeRecursive.TotalMilliseconds}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Author recursive: {timeAuthor.TotalMilliseconds}");
}

private static void WarmUp()
{
    var warmUpTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4);

    var watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();

    while (watch.Elapsed < warmUpTime)
    {
        var x = Math.Pow(12, 5) * Math.Cos(55.2);
        x /= 20;
    }
}

private static TimeSpan TestTimeExecution(Func<int[], int> method, List<int[]> testSrc)
{
    var watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();

    foreach (var input in testSrc)
    {
        method(input);
    }

    watch.Stop();
    return watch.Elapsed;
}
```

**Результаты:**

> Classic         : 112,5684
>
> Recursive       : 769,2986
>
> Author recursive: 1475,7236

**Выводы:** Классический метод >10 раз быстрее предложенного вами рекурсивного метода поиска максимума и ~6-7 раз быстрее предложенного мною рекурсивного метода.

**P.S.** В измерении скорости выполнения методов не силен. Результаты имеют приближенный характер

Comment: Здравствуйте. Спасибо за ответ. Проверил ваш вариант рекурсии - не подошло.  Проверяется массив длинной в 10млн. Мой дешманский ноут долго пыхтит, а потом пишет, что Test run aborted.